# How to delete an element of a spinner and update the spinner list and the db SQLite

Tags: android

I have a spinner that show my data list from a database SQLite.. I want to remove a row from Spinner and db when selected then clicked button btn. How can I do this? Thanks

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remove_wf2);

        mDB = new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext()); 
        mDB.open();
        spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.wf_spinner);

        c = mDB.fetchWfs();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
        String[] from = new String[]{WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY};
        // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        // create simple cursor adapter
        adapter =
          new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
        // get reference to our spinner
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);

        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                spinnerPos = pos;
                mRowId = id;  // database row id
            }
        });

        //fillSpinner(spin);


        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
        btn.setText("Rimuovi");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDB.delete_byID(mRowId);
                c.requery();


            }
        });
        /*
        Spinner spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.wf_spinner);
        Cursor cur = mDB.fetchWfs();
        startManagingCursor(cur);

        String[] from = new String[] { WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY };
        int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
        SimpleCursorAdapter spinAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cur, from, to);
        spinAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(spinAdapter);

        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                mSpinnerWF = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY));
            }
            @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });*/
        //mDB.close();
    }
```

My delete method is this:

```
public boolean delete_byID(long rowId) {
        return mDb.delete(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;

    CharSequence text = "Il Workflow "+ n +" è stato rimosso con successo!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    }
```

I don't find any delete method from ID. Is this a db method?

I've modified my app like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remove_wf2);

        mDB = new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext()); 
        mDB.open();
        spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.wf_spinner);

        c = mDB.fetchWfs();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
        String[] from = new String[]{WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY};
        // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        // create simple cursor adapter
        adapter =
          new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
        // get reference to our spinner
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);

        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                spinnerPos = pos;
                mRowId = id;  // database row id
            }
        });

        //fillSpinner(spin);
        mDB.close();

        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
        btn.setText("Rimuovi");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                adapter.getItem(spinnerPos);
                mDB.delete_byName((String)adapter.getItem(spinnerPos));
                c.requery();


            }
        });
```

but I get this error in LogCat(Cast exception):

```
05-10 15:46:38.586: D/RadioSignalLevel(1758): Gsm Radio Signal level: 4
05-10 15:46:38.586: D/StatusBarPolicy(1758): ERI alert sound is disabled.
05-10 15:46:38.606: D/NetworkService(1939): handle message:800
05-10 15:46:38.606: D/NetworkService(1939): getRawGPRSRegistrationState
05-10 15:46:38.616: I/TransactionService(29090): MMS-STATUS - start transaction service, app version=STABLE4.5.user.4.5.2A-74_OLE-31.2.3.4.Blur_Version.45.31.0.MB860.TIM.en.IT.Thu Sep 22 04:02:02 CST 2011 (log=false) (apn=false) (config=false)
05-10 15:46:38.626: I/SmsReceiverService(29090): MMS-STATUS - start sms receiver service, app version=STABLE4.5.user.4.5.2A-74_OLE-31.2.3.4.Blur_Version.45.31.0.MB860.TIM.en.IT.Thu Sep 22 04:02:02 CST 2011 (log=false) (apn=false) (config=false)
05-10 15:46:38.636: I/TelephonyRegistry(1610): notifyDataConnection: state=0 isDataConnectivityPossible=false reason=nwTypeChanged interfaceName=null networkType=10
05-10 15:46:38.636: I/SYS_MPP(1965): WebtopStatusHandler    updateDataIcon()
05-10 15:46:38.646: D/NetworkService(1939): handle message:800
05-10 15:46:38.646: D/NetworkService(1939): getRawGPRSRegistrationState
05-10 15:46:38.646: I/CBStartup(1939): onServiceStateChanged
05-10 15:46:38.656: I/CBSettings(1939): Reading database: KEY_NAME= db_key_language
05-10 15:46:38.656: I/CBSettings(1939): Reading database: KEY_NAME= db_key_channel


public class MyDatabase {  

    SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    DbHelper mDbHelper;
    Context mContext;
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "WFListDatabase";
    private static final String DB_NAME="WFListdb";//nome del db
    private static final int DB_VERSION=1; //numero di versione del nostro db

    public MyDatabase(Context ctx) {
        mContext = ctx;
        mDbHelper = new DbHelper(ctx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);   //quando istanziamo questa classe, istanziamo anche l'helper (vedi sotto)     
    }

   public void open(){  //il database su cui agiamo è leggibile/scrivibile
            mDb=mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    public void close(){ //chiudiamo il database su cui agiamo
            mDb.close();
    }


    public void insertWf(String name,String cls){ //metodo per inserire i dati
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY, name);
            cv.put(WfMetaData.WF_CLASS_KEY, cls);
            mDb.insert(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, null, cv);
    }



    /*public void removeWf(String name,String cls){ //metodo per inserire i dati
        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
        cv.remove(WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY);
        cv.remove(WfMetaData.WF_CLASS_KEY);
        mDb.(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, null, cv);
}*/



    public Cursor fetchAllWfs(){ //metodo per fare la query di tutti i dati
        return mDb.query(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, new String[]{WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY, WfMetaData.WF_CLASS_KEY},null,null,null,null,null);               
    }

    static class WfMetaData {  // i metadati della tabella, accessibili ovunque
    static final String WF_TABLE = "wfs";
    static final String ID = "_id";
    static final String WF_NAME_KEY = "name";
    static final String WF_CLASS_KEY = "class";
    }


    private static final String WF_TABLE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "  //codice sql di creazione della tabella
                    + WfMetaData.WF_TABLE + " (" 
                    + WfMetaData.ID+ " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY + " text not null, "
                    + WfMetaData.WF_CLASS_KEY + " text not null);";

    public Cursor fetchWfs(){ //metodo per fare la query di tutti i dati
        return mDb.query(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, null,null,null,null,null,null);               
}

    public void delete_byName(String n){
     mDb.delete(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY + "='" +n + "'", null);
     //mDb.delete(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY + "=?", new String[] { n });

    CharSequence text = "Il Workflow "+ n +" è stato rimosso con successo!";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, text, duration);
    toast.show();
    }


    public void delete_byID(long rowId) {
        mDb.delete(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY + "=" + rowId, null);

        CharSequence text = "Il Workflow è stato rimosso con successo!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

   private class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { //classe che ci aiuta nella creazione del db

        public DbHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) { //solo quando il db viene creato, creiamo la tabella
            _db.execSQL(WF_TABLE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Upgrading database. Existing contents will be lost. ["
                    + oldVersion + "]->[" + newVersion + "]");
            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + WF_TABLE_CREATE);
            onCreate(_db);
        }       

    }


    public boolean isEmpty(){
        boolean isEmpty = true;
        Cursor cursor = mDb.query(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, new String[] { WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY }, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
           isEmpty = false;
        }
        return isEmpty;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class RemoveWorkflow2 extends Activity {

    private EditText nameEditText;
    private EditText classEditText;
    //private EditText idEditText;
    //private int mSpinnerWF;
    Spinner spin;
    WorkflowChoice wf = new WorkflowChoice();

    MyDatabase mDB;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    private long mRowId;
    private int spinnerPos;
    private String delString;
    Cursor c;
    //MyDatabase mDB = wf.getDb();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remove_wf2);

        mDB = new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext()); 
        mDB.open();
        spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.wf_spinner);

        c = mDB.fetchWfs();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
        String[] from = new String[]{WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY};
        // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        // create simple cursor adapter
        adapter =
          new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
        // get reference to our spinner
        spin.setAdapter(adapter);

        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                Cursor c = (Cursor)(parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos));
                delString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(mDB.);
                //spinnerPos = pos;
                //mRowId = id;  // database row id
            }
        });

        //fillSpinner(spin);


        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
        btn.setText("Rimuovi");
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mDB.delete_byID(mRowId);
                mDB.delete_byName(delString);
                c.requery();


            }
        });

    }

    private void fillSpinner(Spinner s){

        Cursor c = mDB.fetchWfs();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        // create an array to specify which fields we want to display
        String[] from = new String[]{WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY};
        // create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
        int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
        // create simple cursor adapter
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter =
          new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
        // get reference to our spinner
        s.setAdapter(adapter);
        }


}
```

I have a problem in method:

```
@Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                Cursor c = (Cursor)(parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos));
                delString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(mDB.);
                //spinnerPos = pos;
                //mRowId = id;  // database row id
            }
```

How can I set delString? I don't have YOUR_COLUMN_ID.. How can I resolve it? THANKS

Comment: I use this: public void onClick(View v) {
    int pos = 0;
    spin.getItemAtPosition(spin.getSelectedItemPosition());
    
    
    //mDB.delete_byName(n)
    
    
   }

Comment: BTW, I see you're new here.  Welcome.  You've asked a few questions but not accepted any answers.  If an answer helps you out you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  If it really helps, you could consider upvoting it too (click the up arrow).  This does two things:  1) It lets people know that your issue is recolved and 2) it gives creit to the person that helped you out.

Comment: Got it working?  Congrats!  (I assume so since my answer was accepted)

Comment: You need to use the column identifier that will give you the string you are looking for to delete.  `delString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY));`

Comment: PERFECT!! Resolved! Thx very much Barak!

Comment: Can You help me in this other post please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581046/create-a-list-with-onclick-listener-on-each-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the button is outside the spinner...

You don't really need the position.  Set a class variable:

```
private int spinnerPos;     
private long mRowId;
```

Add this for your spinner:

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
        spinnerPos = pos;
        mRowId = id;  // database row id
    }
});
```

Then for your button:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Your code to get the string from the adapter
        mDB.delete_byName(yourString);
        c.requery();
});
```

By the way, you should leave your DB open until you are exiting the app.

I see you asking a question about deleting by id.  In your database class you would have something like this:

```
public boolean delete(long rowId) {
    return mDb.delete(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT**

Better method:

```
Private String delString;
```

Add this for your spinnerListener

```
spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int pos, long id) {
            Cursor c = (Cursor) (parent.getAdapter().getItem(pos));
            delString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(YourDB.YOUR_COLUMN_ID));       }
});
```

Button:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mDB.delete_byName(delString);
        c.requery();
});
```

**EDIT 2**

First Method for delete (by RowId):

```
public boolean delete_byID(long rowId) {
    return mDb.delete(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, WfMetaData.ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

Second Method for delete (by name):

```
public boolean delete_byName(String name) {
    return mDb.delete(WfMetaData.WF_TABLE, WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY + "= '" + name + "'", null) > 0;
}
```

Comment: @darkmax, updated my answer.  It's almost the same.  You use the `onItemSelected` to give you the position just like it gives you the row id.

Comment: I've modified the code but I have a cast exeption.. why? I've posted the mod

Comment: I don't see a cast exception in that post... But I do see a problem in the code you posted...  You closed the DB and then tried to access it.  Remove the `mDB.close();` and see what happens.

Comment: I've edit the method. I put mDB.close(9 in a comment.. Just try to click the button but nothing heppens..

Comment: I've posted a better method (at the end of my answer under the EDIT).  Give it a try.  (Still need to leave the DB open though).

Comment: And your delete didn't work because you didn't change the column you were comparing in your SQL statement.  At least I assume `WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY` is not the row id, since that was what was there when you were doing it by name.  You can change that to be the var you use for the rowid, or use my second edit and revert the method back to doing it by name.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.. I've posted MyDatabase class.. How can I change it to work?

Comment: delString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(YourDB.YOUR_COLUMN_ID)); I have not YOUR_COLUMN_ID when I put mDB. Why?