# Create a list with onClick listener on each item

Tags: java, android

I have a `SQLite` db and I want to see in a ListView all the elements. But I want to make every row clickable. How to do this? Here is the code:
Then.. another question.. I have an activity that I can launched by the options menu and it add or remove data from the db.. I want to autoupdate the list when i come back to this activity.. How can I change the code?.

```
public class WorkflowChoice extends Activity
{
    private static final int INIT_JADE_PROFILE = 0;
    private static final int MANAGE_DATABASE = 1;
    private static final int MODIFY_FILES = 2;
    private static final int CHANGE_THEME = 3;
    private static final int SHOW_OUTPUT_WORKFLOW = 4;
    private LinearLayout properties_container;
    private MyDatabase db;
    TextView wfsTv;
    ListView wfsLv;
    private Cursor c;
    public MyDatabase getDb()
    {
        return db;
    }
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choice);
        properties_container = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.properties_container);
        String host = (String) InitJadeProperties.retrieve(this, getString(R.string.main_container_host), getString(R.string.default_host));
        String port = (String) InitJadeProperties.retrieve(this, getString(R.string.main_container_port), getString(R.string.default_port));
        wfsTv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wfsTv);
        ListView wfsLv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.wfsLv);
        db=new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        db.open();
        //apriamo il db
        if(db.fetchWfs().getCount()==0)
        {
            //inserimento dati, solo se il db è vuoto
            db.insertWf("WF1", "class1");
            db.insertWf("WF2", "class2");
            db.insertWf("WF3", "class3");
            db.insertWf("WF4", "class4");
            db.insertWf("WF5", "class5");
        }
        c=db.fetchWfs();
        // query
        startManagingCursor(c);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter( //semplice adapter per i cursor                 this,                  R.layout.wfs, 
        //il layout di ogni riga/prodotto c,new String[]
        {
            MyDatabase.WfMetaData.ID,MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY,MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_CLASS_KEY
        }
        ,//questi colonne 
        new int[]{R.id.IDTv,R.id.nameTv,R.id.classTv }            );
        //in queste views 
        wfsLv.setAdapter(adapter);
        //la listview ha questo adapter //qui vediamo invece come reperire i dati e usarli, in questo caso li stampiamo in una textview
        int nameCol=c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY);
        //indici delle colonne
        int classCol=c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_CLASS_KEY);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            //se va alla prima entry, il cursore non è vuoto         do
            {
                wfsTv.append("Wf Name:"+c.getString(nameCol)+", Class:"+c.getString(classCol)+"\n");
                //estrazione dei dati dalla entry del cursor
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
            //iteriamo al prossimo elemento
        }
        db.close();
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
        //visto che usiamo i gradient, usiamo questo trick (vedi snippet forum) getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);
        //wfsLv.setBackgroundDrawable(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]
        {
            Color.RED,Color.parseColor("#f2bf26")
        }
        ));
        //wfsTv.setBackgroundDrawable(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]
        {
            Color.RED,Color.parseColor("#f2bf26")
        }
        ));
        //definizione ed uso di gradient in modo programmatico //animazioni in modo programmatico (vedi snippet forum) Animation a1 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        a1.setDuration(1000);
        a1.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator));
        wfsLv.startAnimation(a1);
        //entra da sotto Animation a2 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        a2.setDuration(1000);
        a2.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator));
        wfsTv.startAnimation(a2);
        //entra da sopra wfsLv.setClickable(true);
        //e affidiamo la gestione del tap/click ad un apposito listener, che ci permetterà di agire sull’elemento cliccato e ricaricare la nostra lista wfsLv.setOnItemClickListener        (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView&lt;
            ?&gt;
            parent,           View v, int position, long id)
            {
                TextView txtId = (TextView)           v.findViewById(R.id.wfsTv);
                c.requery();
            }
        }
        );
        /*wfsTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override         public void onClick(View v)
            {
                CharSequence text = "Workflow scelto!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
        );
        */     TextView masterTv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.masterTv);
        masterTv.setText("Master");
        masterTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override         public void onClick(View v)
            {
                startSubActivity();
            }
        }
        );
    }
    private void startSubActivity()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConfigChoice.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

EDIT

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choice);

        properties_container = (LinearLayout ) findViewById(R.id.properties_container);

        String host = (String) InitJadeProperties.retrieve(this, getString(R.string.main_container_host), getString(R.string.default_host));
        String port = (String) InitJadeProperties.retrieve(this, getString(R.string.main_container_port), getString(R.string.default_port));

        wfsTv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wfsTv);
        ListView wfsLv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.wfsLv);

        db=new MyDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        db.open();  //apriamo il db


        if(db.fetchWfs().getCount()==0){//inserimento dati, solo se il db è vuoto

                db.insertWf("WF1", "class1");
                db.insertWf("WF2", "class2");
                db.insertWf("WF3", "class3");
                db.insertWf("WF4", "class4");
                db.insertWf("WF5", "class5"); 

        }

        c=db.fetchWfs(); // query
        startManagingCursor(c);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter( //semplice adapter per i cursor
                        this, 
                        R.layout.wfs, //il layout di ogni riga/prodotto 
                        c, 
                        new String[]{MyDatabase.WfMetaData.ID,MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY,MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_CLASS_KEY},//questi colonne 
                        new int[]{R.id.IDTv,R.id.nameTv,R.id.classTv});//in queste views

        wfsLv.setAdapter(adapter); //la listview ha questo adapter

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //qui vediamo invece come reperire i dati e usarli, in questo caso li stampiamo in una textview

        int nameCol=c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_NAME_KEY);  //indici delle colonne
        int classCol=c.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.WfMetaData.WF_CLASS_KEY);       

        if(c.moveToFirst()){  //se va alla prima entry, il cursore non è vuoto
                do {

                        wfsTv.append("Wf Name:"+c.getString(nameCol)+", Class:"+c.getString(classCol)+"\n"); //estrazione dei dati dalla entry del cursor

                        } while (c.moveToNext());//iteriamo al prossimo elemento
        }

        db.close();
        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);   //visto che usiamo i gradient, usiamo questo trick (vedi snippet forum)
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DITHER);  

        //wfsLv.setBackgroundDrawable(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BOTTOM_TOP, new int[]{Color.RED,Color.parseColor("#f2bf26")}));
        //wfsTv.setBackgroundDrawable(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]{Color.RED,Color.parseColor("#f2bf26")}));
        //definizione ed uso di gradient in modo programmatico


        //animazioni in modo programmatico (vedi snippet forum)
        Animation a1 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        a1.setDuration(1000);
        a1.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator));
        wfsLv.startAnimation(a1);
        //entra da sotto


        Animation a2 = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
        a2.setDuration(1000);
        a2.setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.loadInterpolator(this, android.R.anim.decelerate_interpolator));
        wfsTv.startAnimation(a2);
        //entra da sopra


        wfsLv.setClickable(true);
        //e affidiamo la gestione del tap/click ad un apposito listener, che ci permetterà di agire sull’elemento cliccato e ricaricare la nostra lista

        wfsLv.setOnItemClickListener
               (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                  View v, int position, long id) {
         //TextView txtId = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.wfsTv); 
         CharSequence text = "Workflow scelto!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);
            toast.show();
         c.requery(); 
        }
               });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
       //---> arg2 <-- will give you row number
       // your code goes here
    }
});
```

and to change data

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```